# imfilter speed for volumes

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I'm working on an algorithm, which requires filtering of a 3D matrix (non-sparse, 512^3) to find edges.
I only want to find edges in each slice, so I have been doing the following:

```
% 2D loop appaoch    
[x,y]=ndgrid(floor(-3*sigma):ceil(3*sigma),floor(-3*sigma):ceil(3*sigma));    
DGauss=-(x./(2*pi*sigma^4)).*exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/(2*sigma^2));    
filteredVolume = zeros(size(vol))    
for n = 1:size(vol,3)      
    filteredVolume(:,:,n) = imfilter(vol(:,:,n),DGauss,'conv','symmetric');    
end
```

I also tried to do the same by calling imfilter on the entire volume:

```
% 3D matrix approach    
filteredVolume = imfilter(vol,DGauss,'conv','symmetric');
```

I compared the performance of both of these approaches, but the loop version is significantly faster (6.5 seconds to 20 seconds).
Should this behavior be expected? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it takes longer with the 3D version is because `imfilter` decides that the filter is non-separable.  The function `imfilter>isSeparable` says the following:

```
function separable = isSeparable(a, h)

% check for filter separability only if the kernel has at least
% 289 elements [17x17] (non-double input) or 49 [7x7] (double input),
% both the image and the filter kernel are two-dimensional and the
% kernel is not a row or column vector, nor does it contain any NaNs of Infs
```

Since the input image is not 2D, the function returns `false` and a 2D filtering operation is done instead of two sequential 1D filters, which are faster.

On a side note, `imfilter` does not benefit from the JIT compiler.  All the time is spent in the compiled function `images\private\imfilter_mex`.