# 3D Convolution C/C++ Code for Small Kernels

Tags: c++, c, 3d, convolution

I am looking for a fast `C` (or `C++`) code that does 3D convolution with small kernels. What I have found online so far are based on `FFT` and require the use of other libraries. However, as pointed out by many, these `FFT`-based convolution codes are not suitable for small kernels (in my case they are mainly `3×3×3` or `5×5×5`). Is there a `C/C++` code that directly implements 3D convolution algorithm? I can implement a 3D convolution in a code according to its definition. However, what I write will not be the most efficient and fast implementation. I am actually looking for a code that has been verified in this aspect.

Comment: Convolution is just multiplying and adding.  What's the problem?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you are looking for.  http://www.programming-techniques.com/2013/02/calculating-convolution-of-image-with-c_2.html

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I know how to implement a 3D convolution. For sure, what I write is not the most efficient and fast implementation. I am actually looking for a code that has been verified in this aspect.

Comment: @A2009 that is so vague to me ... define target complexity instead so we are clear what you want. Something faster then `O(N^3)` perhaps? where `N` is the size of square array? from your duplicate question is `N` around `200`. btw do not make duplicate questions instead improve the current ones. PS for FFT you do not need a lib you can code it yourself it is not that hard

Comment: @A2009 here another almost the same question http://stackoverflow.com/q/20554666/2521214