# Passing mxArray to mexCallMatlab fails

Tags: matlab, mex

I am writing a mex file in which `conv2` function is called. This `mex` file will get an image of size `(M, N)` and apply convolution several time using `conv2`.

```
#include "mex.h"

void myconv( mxArray *Ain, mxArray *Kernel, mxArray *&Aout )
{

    mxArray *rhs[3];

    rhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL );
    rhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 0, 0, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL );
    rhs[2] = mxCreateString       ( "same" );

    double *ainPtr = mxGetPr( Ain   );
    mxSetPr( rhs[0], ainPtr         );
    mxSetM ( rhs[0], mxGetM(Ain)    );
    mxSetN ( rhs[0], mxGetM(Ain)    );

    double *kernelPtr = mxGetPr( Kernel );
    mxSetPr( rhs[1], kernelPtr          );
    mxSetM ( rhs[1], mxGetM(Kernel)     );
    mxSetN ( rhs[1], mxGetN(Kernel)     );

    mexCallMATLAB(1, &Aout, 3, rhs, "conv2");

    mxSetPr( rhs[0], NULL ); 
    mxSetPr( rhs[1], NULL );

}

void myconv_combine( mxArray *Ain, mxArray *&Aout )
{

    mxArray *mask = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 1, 5, mxREAL );

    double *maskPtr = mxGetPr( mask );
    maskPtr[0] = 0.05; 
    maskPtr[1] = 0.25; 
    maskPtr[2] = 0.4; 
    maskPtr[3] = 0.25; 
    maskPtr[4] = 0.05;

    mxArray *maskTranspose = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 0, 0, mxREAL );
    mxSetPr( maskTranspose, maskPtr      );
    mxSetM ( maskTranspose, mxGetN(mask) );
    mxSetN ( maskTranspose, mxGetM(mask) );

    mxArray *AinConvolved = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( (mwSize)mxGetM(Ain), (mwSize)mxGetN(Ain), mxREAL );
    double *AinConvolvedPtr = mxGetPr( AinConvolved );
    myconv( Ain, mask, AinConvolved );

    // Some modifications.
    mxArray *Temp = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( (mwSize)mxGetM(Ain), (mwSize)mxGetN(Ain), mxREAL );
    double *TempPtr = mxGetPr( Temp );
    for( int i = 0; i < (mwSize)mxGetM(Ain)*(mwSize)mxGetN(Ain); i++ )
            TempPtr[ i ] = 2.0*AinConvolvedPtr[ i ];

    // Some other convolution.
    mxArray *TempConvolved = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( (mwSize)mxGetM(Ain), (mwSize)mxGetN(Ain), mxREAL );
    double *TempConvolvedPtr = mxGetPr( TempConvolved );
    myconv( Temp, maskTranspose, TempConvolved );

    // Some other modifications.
    double *AoutPtr = mxGetPr( Aout );
    for( int i = 0; i < (mwSize)mxGetM(Ain)*(mwSize)mxGetN(Ain); i++ )
            AoutPtr[ i ] = 2.0*TempConvolvedPtr[ i ];


}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

   mxArray *Ain  = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 100, 100, mxREAL );
   mxArray *Aout = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 100, 100, mxREAL );

   myconv_combine( Ain, Aout );


}
```

In my actual code, when it reaches the line:

```
myconv( Temp, maskTranspose, TempConvolved );
```

MATLAB crashes which I have no clue why this happens and unfortunately I could not duplicate the same error in the example code I provided above. In my actual code, the image is convolved successfully by line:

```
myconv( Ain, mask, AinConvolved );
```

However, as soon as it wants to apply a second convolution:

```
myconv( Temp, maskTranspose, TempConvolved );
```

It crashes and when I debug it, it occurs when `mexCallMATLAB` is called on `myconv` function. What can be the difference between  `Temp`/`TempConvolved` and `Ain`/`AinConvolved` that makes the former crash at the time of  `mexCallMATLAB`?

Could someone kindly help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reusing data buffers**

Reusing the data pointer from `mxArray *mask` for `mxArray *maskTransposed` is asking for trouble, as MATLAB has rigorous mechanisms for reference counting as shared-data arrays are an important part of MATLAB's memory optimizations. Instead, duplicate the whole thing with [`mxDuplicateArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxduplicatearray.html?refresh=true):

```
mxArray *maskTranspose = mxDuplicateArray(mask);
```

There is an undocumented [`mxCreateSharedDataCopy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850676/2778484) that emulates MATLAB's lazy-copy mechanism, but that's really overkill for a 5-element array.

**Superfluous-to-problematic `mxArray` initialization prior to `mexCallMATLAB`**

Also, do not bother initializing `mxArray *AinConvolved` before calling `mexCallMATLAB`.  Just pass a NULL pointer and it will create it for you.  If you don't it will just wipe the old one (send it to garbage collection) and create a fresh one for the output of `conv2`.  Which reminds me this demonstrates how this is a problem in your code:

```
mxArray *AinConvolved = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mxGetM(Ain), mxGetN(Ain), mxREAL);
double *AinConvolvedPtr0 = mxGetPr(AinConvolved);
myconv(Ain, mask, AinConvolved);
double *AinConvolvedPtr = mxGetPr(AinConvolved);
mexPrintf("%p\n%p\n", AinConvolvedPtr0, AinConvolvedPtr);
```

Output in MATLAB:

```
00000000B852FA20
0000000026B8EB00
```

As you can see, if you try to use the pointer you got with `mxGetPr` before using `mexCallMATLAB`, you're probably using the wrong data, possibly already deallocated memory..

**Automatic separable filtering with `imfilter`**

Also, note that if you have `imfilter`, you don't need to implement separable convolution because it has  that functionality built in.  Just have a look at `imfilter.m` and note the `isSeparable` function.  See [here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284313/2778484).

Try that, I'll post a test.

Comment: I changed my code and used `mxArray *AinConvolved= NULL;` and `mxArray *TempConvolved = NULL;`. I also tried `myconv( Temp, mask, TempConvolved );` to eliminate the potential of causing reference counting and used `mask` instead of `maskTranspose`. However, it still does not work and the problem happens in the same place as before, where `TempConvolved` cannot be computed.

Comment: @A2009 How about placement of `mxGetPr(AinConvolved)` and `mxGetPr( TempConvolved )` after their calls to `mexCallMATLAB`?  Is there any code that can reproduce that you can post, perhaps on gist.github.com for a large amount of code?

Comment: Let me see how I can reproduce the erroneous part to better clarify the issue. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have uploaded a code here: https://gist.github.com/afalahat/cb48ede7eab0d92d161d

Comment: @A2009 Your code has the same issue of resuing data buffers.  The buffer set by `mxSetPr` must be created only by `mxMalloc` or `mxCalloc`. Don't create `Bt1[0]` with the `double*` from `mxGetPr( prhs[0] )`.  Just pass `prhs[0]` to `Reduce`.

Comment: The reason I prefer to do this is that the input image is of size `(NY, NX, NT)`, where `NT` is the number of the images in time. I actually want to do this task for every image at every timestep.

Comment: @A2009 Understood, but it's the [same issue as before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27068004/2778484), specifically [this discussion point](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20077783#20077783).  If you pass in a pyramid, two options:  put each level as it's own input argument or use a cell array with [`mxGetCell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetcell.html?refresh=true).  It's very easy to pass a cell.

Comment: Got you. Does using `mxGetCell` force me to copy the values?